# Debugger des not step into the function even if conditions are met

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-services, javascript-debugger

On the project: https://github.com/kawai-developers/faster (branch dimitris) on file `www/js/services.js` around line 254 I have the folloging code:

```
game.remove_deleted_items=function()
{
  var deleted=move_items_on_the_top();

  game.grid.loopItems(function(item,i,j,values,game)
  {
    console.log(item.status);
    if(item.status==='destroyed')
    {
      console.log("Δαμέ");
      values[i][j]= game.randomItem(values[i][j]);//Replace the item with the new one
      game.addScore(1);
    }
  });
};
```

But for some reason even though the following line is executed:

```
values[i][j]= game.randomItem(values[i][j]);
```

The line below is not:

```
  game.addScore(1);
```

Both of them are in the same condition and game item is accessible. Also the method exists and has the following implementation:

```
game.addScore=function(points)
{
  console.log(points);
  game.points.value+=points;
  console.log("Helllo adding points");
}
```

But on my debugger (firefox one) I debug it for some reason when I click to step in to the function `gamme.addScore` it does not.

DO you have any Idea why does that happen?

Comment: So neither running the code normally nor using the debugger will hit `console.log(points);`? It just never gets hit? What if you put a log below `game.addScore(1);`, does that get hit?

Comment: Well neither the way you suggested woorked I just put the  game.addScore(1); into an another place and woorked like a charm.

Comment: I didn't make any suggestions about how to make it work, I was just trying to figure out exactly what was happening. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the  game.addScore(1); outside the callback so the `game.remove_deleted_items` is:

```
game.remove_deleted_items=function()
        {
          var deleted=move_items_on_the_top();
          if(deleted)
          {
            deleted.forEach(function()
            {
              game.addScore(1);
            });
          }

          // I Loop through the grid because I want the i,j position for each item too.
          game.grid.loopItems(function(item,i,j,values,game)
          {
            console.log(item.status);
            if(item.status==='destroyed')
            {
              values[i][j]= game.randomItem(values[i][j]);//Replace the item with the new one
            }
          });
        };
```

(With a pinch of documentation)